# Setting LD_PRELOAD path saves the process from getting Segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux, linker, segmentation-fault, loader

My application `obuspa` is crashing when it is executing the standard OpenWRT library call `uci_lookup_ptr` of the `libuci.so` linked library. Loader is showing this library in the list of linked libraries as below

```
# /lib/ld-linux.so.3 --list /sbin/obuspa
        libmosquitto.so.1 => /usr/lib/libmosquitto.so.1 (0xb68de000)
        libubus.so => /usr/lib/libubus.so (0xb68cf000)
        libubox.so => /usr/lib/libubox.so (0xb68bb000)
        libblobmsg_json.so => /usr/lib/libblobmsg_json.so (0xb68b0000)
        libuci.so => /lib/libuci.so (0xb689e000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xb6766000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.3 (0xb6f2d000)
```

If the same library is set in shell environment using ld_preload like below, and application is restarted, the process is running fine and not recieving any `SIGSEGV` signal at all. Hence, no `SEGFAULT`.

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/lib/libuci.so
```

Below is the code:

```
static int get_value_from_uci(char *path, char *value, size_t max_value_len)
{
    struct uci_context *uci_ctx;
    struct uci_ptr ptr;
    int ret = 0;

    if (!path || !value || max_value_len == 0)
            return -1;

    uci_ctx = uci_alloc_context();
    if (!uci_ctx)
            return -1;

    printf("%s, uci ctx : %p created, lookup for %s\n", __FUNCTION__, uci_ctx, path);
    if (uci_lookup_ptr(uci_ctx, &ptr, path, true) != UCI_OK) {
            ret = -1;
            uci_free_context(uci_ctx);
            printf("%s, uci lookup failed\n", __FUNCTION__);
            return ret;
    }
    printf("%s, uci ptr flag:%d\n", __FUNCTION__, ptr.flags);
    if ((ptr.flags & UCI_LOOKUP_COMPLETE)
            && (ptr.o != NULL)
            && (ptr.o->v.string!=NULL)) {
            ret = 0;
            USP_STRNCPY(value, ptr.o->v.string, max_value_len);
            printf("%s, uci lookup completed, value:%s\n", __FUNCTION__, value);
    }
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    char cached_json_file[256] = {0};
    char uci_role_path[] = "obuspa.global.dm_caching_exclude";
    
    // Read rest of the roles from JSON, if defined
    printf("%s, GET UCI Role\n", __FUNCTION__);
    if (get_value_from_uci(uci_role_path, cached_json_file, 256) != 0)
            goto exit;
    ....
    return 0;
}
```

***Library source code link:***
https://git.openwrt.org/?p=project/uci.git;a=tree

How setting same shared library path, save the process from crash.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `export LD_PRELOAD=/lib/libuci.so` with `/etc/ld.so.preload` file:

add just line `/lib/libuci.so` to file `/etc/ld.so.preload`, you may have to create it.

From [man 8 ld.so](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html):

> `/etc/ld.so.preload`
>
> File containing a whitespace-separated list of ELF shared
> objects to be loaded before the program.  See the
> discussion of `LD_PRELOAD` above.  If both LD_PRELOAD and
> `/etc/ld.so.preload` are employed, the libraries specified
> by `LD_PRELOAD` are preloaded first.  `/etc/ld.so.preload` has
> a system-wide effect, causing the specified libraries to
> be preloaded for all programs that are executed on the
> system.  (**This is usually undesirable, and is typically
> employed only as an emergency remedy**, for example, as a
> temporary workaround to a library misconfiguration issue.)

---

If you don’t want to use `/etc/ld.so.preload` file, you can create a script file that will set `LD_PRELOAD` each time you try to launch `obuspa`:

**obuspa.sh**

```
#! /bin/sh
export LD_PRELOAD=/lib/libuci.so
/sbin/obuspa "$@"
```

Comment: Hi Mathieu - I was trying to understand how setting `LD_PRELOAD` avoids crash. Shall you please explain on that part.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. But you can investigate compiling with debbuging informations (`gcc -g`) and launch your program trhough `gdb`

Answer (score 0):

When you use LD_PRELOAD this changes the order in which the .so libs are loaded, in the sense that libuci.so is loaded first, then the other libs.
Now, there probably is some memory corruption in your code, which initially damaged the memory where libuci.so was loaded, or memory that libuci.so used and expected to have strict values, and when you called the function it crashed.
What happens now, probably, is that some other function in another lib (e.g. libc.so) gets corrupted. But since you never call that corrupted function, there is no crash.
You need to have a deeper look at your code: are you getting an error somewhere and passing a null pointer to another function? Are you passing a buffer to a function that writes more data than the buffer can hold?
These things are tricky and frustrating to track down, but finding the issue eventually is satisfying ;-) Good luck!

Comment: Hi SaintMath - I checked and confirmed that there is no problem with other shared libraries. Only problem lies with `libuci.so`. Any chance for LD_PRELOAD to trap `SIGSEGV` signal.

Comment: Even I did ld preload for other shared libraries separately and the application crashed. Only if I do it for `libuci.so`, process not crashing.

Comment: @renga_in_stack What chain of events led you to use LD_PRELOAD when your application was crashing? What I'm saying is, I have a feeling you have tried other things that were not successful, and eventually you found LD_PRELOAD. Maybe those other things you tried can provide more info.

Comment: @renga_in_stack Nonetheless providing code around your usage of `uci_lookup_ptr` could prove more useful than any other type of discussion.

Comment: Actually, my target rootfs except `/home, /logs` are `Read-only`. So, not able to replace my version having additional logs in standard /lib/libuci.so path. To encounter this case, I just went ahead with `LD_PRELOAD` way. When I started using LD_PRELOAD, both my version`(LD_PRELOAD=/home/libuci.so)` and the std version`(LD_PRELOAD=/lib/libuci.so)` path are not crashing at all. For your reference, I have updated the code also in `Description`.

Comment: No prints after the lookup call and the process crashed.